# Move values between columns in MYSQL (?)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to move the value of 3 different columns between them but I can't make it works correctly

```
<?php

include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';
include_once 'db_manual_connect.php';


$error_msg = "";
if (isset($_POST['value'], $_POST['id'])) {
$value= $_POST['value'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

    if (!$conn) {
         die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE equipo SET 
    slot1= CASE WHEN slot1= '".$value."' THEN slot1
                    WHEN slot2= '".$value."' THEN slot2
                    WHEN slot3= '".$value."' THEN slot3 END,

    slot2= CASE WHEN slot1= '".$value."' THEN slot2
                    WHEN slot2= '".$value."' THEN slot1
                    WHEN slot3 = '".$value."' THEN slot2 END,

    pokemon3 = CASE WHEN slot1= '".$value."' THEN slot3
                    WHEN slot2= '".$value."' THEN slot3
                    WHEN slot3= '".$value."' THEN slot1 END WHERE id = '".$id."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Can you please explain that *trying to move value of 3 different columns* a bit more in detail. Please also give an example of the data before and how it should be after the update.

Comment: update you question add proper  data sample and the expected  result

Comment: MySQL doesn't work that way. The second `set` will use the already overwritten value. With `Update ... set a = b, b = a` you will end up with the original value of column `b` in both columns. You can do your switcheroo by using additional helper columns; also you might want to do it in seperate steps first, and then combine it when it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a query like this. first you must save the values from slot1-3 in local variables and the you can test and set the fields.

```
UPDATE  theTable t
CROSS join ( SELECT @tmp_slot1:=0, @tmp_slot2:=0, @tmp_slot3:=0) AS init
set 
    t.slot1 = @tmp_slot1 := t.slot1, -- save the val from slot1 into @tmp_slot1
    t.slot2 = @tmp_slot2 := t.slot2, -- save the val from slot2 into @tmp_slot2
    t.slot3 = @tmp_slot2 := t.slot3, -- save the val from slot3 into @tmp_slot3

    t.slot1= CASE WHEN @tmp_slot1= '".$value."' THEN @tmp_slot1
                  WHEN @tmp_slot2= '".$value."' THEN @tmp_slot2
                  WHEN @tmp_slot3= '".$value."' THEN @tmp_slot3 END,

    t.slot2= CASE WHEN @tmp_slot1= '".$value."' THEN @tmp_slot2
                  WHEN @tmp_slot2= '".$value."' THEN @tmp_slot1
                 WHEN @tmp_slot3 = '".$value."' THEN @tmp_slot2 END,

    t.pokemon3 = CASE WHEN @tmp_slot1= '".$value."' THEN @tmp_slot3
                      WHEN @tmp_slot2= '".$value."' THEN @tmp_slot3
                      WHEN @tmp_slot3= '".$value."' THEN @tmp_slot1 END
WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

please let me know if it work for you. its nit tested

**sample with 2 fields**

```
mysql> SELECT * from theTable;
+----+-------+-------+
| id | slot1 | slot2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |     3 |     6 |
|  1 |     6 |    12 |
|  1 |     8 |    16 |
|  2 |     5 |    10 |
|  2 |     7 |    14 |
+----+-------+-------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> update  theTable t
    -> CROSS join ( SELECT @tmp_slot1:=0, @tmp_slot2:=0) AS init
    -> set
    ->     slot1 = @tmp_slot1 := slot1,
    ->     slot2 = @tmp_slot2 := slot2,
    ->     slot1 = @tmp_slot2,
    ->     slot2 = @tmp_slot1;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0,00 sec)
Rows matched: 5  Changed: 5  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * from theTable;
+----+-------+-------+
| id | slot1 | slot2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |     6 |     3 |
|  1 |    12 |     6 |
|  1 |    16 |     8 |
|  2 |    10 |     5 |
|  2 |    14 |     7 |
+----+-------+-------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```